# error converting from plist/dictionary to NSNumber

Tags: ios, plist, nsdictionary, nsnumber

I have a plist file that contains some default values,

My goal is to copy these value in an object at runtime,

Half the values are fine, the other are set to nonsense ^^

plist:

```
<dict>
...
<key>averageCostDevelopPerApp</key>
<integer>50000</integer>
...
</dict>
```

printout of the dictionary in debugger:

> averageCostDevelopPerApp = 50000;

printout of my object in the debugger:

> averageCostDevelopPerApp = "-15536";

averageCostDevelopPerApp is declared like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * averageCostDevelopPerApp;
```

and here is where I set the data in the object:

```
[self setAverageCostDevelopPerApp: [dictionary objectForKey:@"averageCostDevelopPerApp"]];
```

I did some digging and what objectforKey returns in a "__NSCFNumber".

I'm guessing I have to do some sor of conversion but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that guys,

discovered in a flash of insperation so common after 12 hours coding @1am, that in the data model, the property was set the intger16...